# How do I make the same iteration for several different lists at the same time in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iterator

if i have multiple lists at different lengths is there a simple way to make the same iteration on all of them.

so insted of writing something like:

```
for item in list1:
    function(item)
for item in list2:
    function(item)
.
.
.
for item in listn:
   function(item)
```

i just write something like:

```
for item in list1,list2,...,listn:
    function(item)
```

I know you can do this by combining the lists by i want something more efficient than having to combine them each time i call the function

Comment: You _could_ just do `for item in list1+list2+list3:` but that is generally **much** less efficient than the techniques shown below by `glglgl` and `thefourtheye`, since it has to create a new list to iterate over. Also, the code shown by  `glglgl` and `thefourtheye` works for other types of iterable objects, not just containers like lists & tuples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tasks which have to do with iteration are covered by the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

There you have a [`chain()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) which can do

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3):
    function(item)
```

BTW, the whole standard lib documentation is worth reading, there are a lot of interesting things which can prevent you from re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), which would give items one by one from individual lists, like this

```
for item in (elem for c_list in (list1, list2, list3) for elem in c_list)):
    function(item)
```

For example,

```
>>> def function(item):
...     print item
... 
>>> list1, list2, list3 = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]
>>> for item in (elem for c_list in (list1, list2, list3) for elem in c_list):
...     function(item)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Note:** The generator expression which we create is not concatenating all the lists, but it just iterates the tuple of lists and then iterates the individual lists to get the elements one by one.

Comment: Although not as succinct as glglgl's code it does have the advantage of not requiring an `import`. OTOH, importing itertool isn't going to break the bank. :)